# VHDL : Type not recognised in the variable declaration region of a function

Tags: function, vhdl, subtype

I am trying to write a function that reads from csv file and formats data to fixed point so it can be used to initialize ROM contents.

The function is contained in a package. The package body looks like:

```
-- Package Body Section
package body file_io_pkg is 


impure function f_init_rom_fixed 
   ( fname : string ;
     path  : string;   
     fsize : integer; 
     int_size : integer;
     dec_size : integer  ) return t_sfixed_vec is 

variable v_csv_file    : csv_file_reader; 
variable v_read_sfixed : t_s16 ;
variable v_sfixed_vec  : t_sfixed_vec;

begin

   v_csv_file.initialize(path&fname);
   v_csv_file.readline;

   l_read:
      for i in 0 to fsize - 1 loop
         v_read_sfixed  := signed(to_sfixed(v_csv_file.read_real, int_size ,- dec_size);   
         v_sfixed_vec(i):= v_read_sfixed; 
      end loop l_read; 

   return v_sfixed_vec;  

end function ;

end package body file_io_pkg;
```

I get the following error when elaborating :

```
Error : 'csv_file_reader' is not declared (VHDL-1241) : C:/FPGA/test_prj/hdl/file_io_pkg.vhd(54)
```

But csv_file_reader is a type defined in csv_file_reader_pk (https://github.com/ricardo-jasinski/vhdl-csv-file-reader)

This package is compiled is imported at the library section of my package.

```
library work;
use work.csv_file_reader_pkg.all;
```

So I can't really see why I am getting this error, any hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the entire contents of the design file(s) containing package file_io_pkg and package body file_io_pkg including the context clause preceding the package declaration plus any dependencies not part of the VHDL language (the Jasinski package source). The library declaration for work is already implicitly provided, second and subsequent appearances have no effect. While not being able to duplicate the problem, lacking several type declarations the type name is wrong (should be `variable v_csv_file    : csv_file_reader_type;`, a typographic error).

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthese, should be `v_read_sfixed  := signed(to_sfixed(v_csv_file.read_real, int_size ,- dec_size));` There may be another error lurking in this statement. The type conversion to type `signed` appears to be an error.

Comment: By making assumptions about the declarations for type marks for `t_s16` and `t_sfixed_vec` as well as the missing package declaration your [package will analyze (compile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRtef.jpg). While those assumptions are likely inaccurate they tell you where the errors are in your package body. There may be further errors in your function f_init_rom_fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`csv_file_reader` is not declared, but `csv_file_reader_type` is. Replacing `csv_file_reader` with `csv_file_reader_type` should fix this error.

Comment: Does the downvote mean that this did not solve your error? Can you provide any more details?